# How do I choose the collection type to return in Scala?

Tags: scala

In case of `Set` or `List`, the choice seems to be easier, but what do I do for Java's `Collection`, `Iterable` equivalent? Do I go for `Seq`? `Traversable`? `GenTraversableOnce`?

Comment: What's your usecase?

Comment: This doesn't merit a full answer but its worth noting that you can return an instance of scala's `Iterable` type, just as you would in Java.

Answer (score 4):

You need to decide based on your need. For example: According to [Scala Documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq) the definition of **Seq** is

> Sequences are special cases of iterable collections of class Iterable. Unlike iterables, sequences always have a defined order of elements. Sequences provide a method apply for indexing.

So if you want to benefit ordering or you want to retrieve element by index you can use Seq

Again according to [Scala Documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Traversable) if you are mainly interested in iteration over your Collection **Traversable** is sufficient

Just notice that there is a general good practice that for your function signature like function return type, use more general (abstract) data type to prevent unnecessary performance penalty for the function callers.

Comment: Shouldn't the input parameters be as abstract as possible and the return value as specific as possible?

Comment: About parameters I agree with you. About return type it really depends. For example imagine a function accepting two Traversable and wants to concat them. What should be the return type? I believe Traversable. So return type abstraction level mainly derives from the parameter abstraction level.  In general, you can be specific in the return type only if you have a valid reason. You should not force any unnecessary performance penalty to the function caller. For example you may be more comfortable using Seq so always return Seq in the function manipulating Collections. This is wrong.

Comment: "_You should not force any unnecessary performance penalty to the function caller._" Why should there be a performance penalty if you declare the return type to be more specific? The implementation does not change whether the return type is `Seq` or `GenTraversableOnce`. "_so always return Seq in the function manipulating Collections is wrong_" I can see your point here.

Comment: Yes, maybe my example was not that precise. I'd rather say for example between `List` and `Traversable` instead of `Seq`. Although my point was general, if B and C are subtype of A. If input parameters are of type A, the return type better to be A. Because for example if the return type is B and user send parameter of type C as input parameter, converting C to B may need some computation but If my return type is A, I do not need any conversion.

Answer (score 3):

As often, it will depend on the needs of your caller.
Traversable is pretty high level (you only get `foreach`) but it might be sufficient. Seq would be used if you need a defined order of elements. GenTraversableOnce would be a bit abstract for me and possibly for your fellow coders.